# How to save files to a separate folder in current folder in Python?

Tags: python, save

I have the following python script which does image cropping based on cordinates.

```
for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
        #draw the bright spot on the image
        #(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        ((cX, cY), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        cv2.circle(bgr_img, (int(cX), int(cY)), int(radius),(255, 0, 0), 1)
        crop_img = bgr_img[max(int(cY)-int(radius)-offset,0):max(int(cY)+int(radius)+offset,0),max(int(cX)-int(radius)-offset,0):max(int(cX)+int(radius)+offset,0)]
        cv2.imwrite('%s_%x_%x.jpg'%(image_file,int(cX),int(cY)),crop_img)
        #cv2.imshow("bump", crop_img)
        print(image_file, int(cX), int(cY), int(radius))
```

Currently, new cropped images are saved into main folder where the main image (image_file) resides. I would like to make a new folder in that directory and save the images into the new folder. I tried using os library but did not work.
Any help ?

Comment: Create a `newdirectory` in your working directory and call cv2.write('./newdirectory/%s_... etc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.mkdir`:

```
cropped_dir = 'cropped_images'
os.mkdir(cropped_dir)

for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
        #draw the bright spot on the image
        #(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        ((cX, cY), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        cv2.circle(bgr_img, (int(cX), int(cY)), int(radius),(255, 0, 0), 1)
        crop_img = bgr_img[max(int(cY)-int(radius)-offset,0):max(int(cY)+int(radius)+offset,0),max(int(cX)-int(radius)-offset,0):max(int(cX)+int(radius)+offset,0)]
        image_name = '{}_{}_{}.jpg'.format(image_file, cX, cY)
        image_path = os.path.join(cropped_dir, image_name)
        cv2.imwrite(image_path)
        #cv2.imshow("bump", crop_img)
        print(image_file, int(cX), int(cY), int(radius))
```

Comment: i want to get the folder of current image which i did as "main_dir = os.path.dirname(image_file). But it did not work when I joined. Any idea ?' Only returns "C:"

Comment: Why not use `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: isn't that for current working directory ? image_file could be anywhere on drive. Working directory for program.py is different from image folder name

Comment: Oh, so the image is not in the current working directory? In that case, yes, `getcwd` won't work. What happens with `os.path.dirname`? (Also, it might be better to ask a new question)

Comment: this is how I got. : "c:/circle_detection\\beautiful.txt"'. The path should be forward slash but when joined, it puts "\\".

Comment: That is OS-dependent, but it should still work for opening files. Does it not?